# Caffeine Cache implementation manually

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, guava, caffeine-cache

Hi I am planning to use `Guava Cache` or `Caffeine Cache` in my application as below way -

On application start `DB` call initiated and store the result into `cache`. I don't want to use expiration or recycling feature of above `cache` means data should present in cache all the time until application restart.

How can I implement any of this cache in my Java Spring Boot Application. I do not want to use Spring's Caching functionality.

I want to update or add the values in cache on certain condition.

Comment: Sounds like you only need a `ConcurrentHashMap`? If you need more features, the native apis with the `asMap()` view should cover most use-cases.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you. Do you have example for `ConcurrentHashMap` and `asMap()` for caching.

Comment: The `Map.computeIfAbsent` is popular, because it avoids [cache stampedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_stampede), and you can [manually](https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrent-map) call get/put/remove. The Caffeine apis ([examples](https://www.baeldung.com/java-caching-caffeine)) offers these with a more caching oriented api, plus additional features like an eviction policy and removal listener. Caffeine's features are all optional so you can enable only those you want during construction. The asMap() and policy() are handy for more advanced usages.